# php file_exists with invalid filename

Tags: php, file-exists

```
<?php
    if(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'\<<<<<<<'))
        echo "YES";
    else
        echo "No";
?>
```

My server is Windows 2003

When I test on my server , the response is YES.

But we all know the file name : "<<<<<<<" is invalid ,SO the file named "<<<<<<<" does not exist

So what is the reason ?

when i echo dirname(**FILE**).'\<<<<<<<';

The output is  C:\website\<<<<<<<

Comment: Check if this still says no? <?=(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'\<<<<<<<')) ? "YES" : "No"; ?>

Comment: echo `dirname(__FILE__).'\<<<<<<<'`, what will output?

Comment: What does `var_dump(is_file(dirname(__FILE__).'\<<<<<<<'));` output?

Comment: i echo dirname(FILE).'\<<<<<<<';

The output is C:\website\<<<<<<<

Answer (score 2):

i think you should check your server file manager manual or windows server guidelines (forum)..
because in any Windows XP/7/8 try to make  folder  with name "con" or "LPT1",this will not allow to generate...so its called "EASTER Egg" problem... and in your case i think this problem is something like easter egg.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your file name is Correct  "<<<<<<<"
if yes then try to echo the whole path first  
 - $filename = dirname(**FILE**) . '\<<<<<<<'; 
 echo $filename;  //  see is it returning you  the correct path